# C++ populate array elements with ifstream

Tags: c++, arrays, delimiter

I am trying to populate a string array from a text file that has '|' delimiters. Right now I am populating the entire file into the first element of the array. I would like each string to populate the next array element.

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("info.dat");
string line;
int counter = 0;
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    getline(infile ,line ,'|');
    b[counter] = line;
    counter++;
    cout << endl;
}
infile.close();

cout << b[0] << endl << b[1];
return 0;
}
```

`b[0]` contains the entire file, while `b[1]` is empty. here is what the `.dat` file contains.

```
green dog|red fish|brass monkey|purpe elephant||||||||||||
```

I am trying to use the b[] array to separate the strings. in my `cout` at the bottom I was expecting "green dog" to print on the first line and "red fish" to print on the second line of the console.

Comment: What *does* your program print though?

Comment: You call `getline(infile, line)` without passing the delimiter in the third parameter. That reads until end-of-line or end-of-file, whichever comes first.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    getline(infile ,line ,'|');
```

should be this

```
while (getline(infile, line, '|'))
{
```

I don't know why you picked the first option when you have '|' delimited data.